# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error on DELETE Method in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http, angular-observable

I am using below method to delete data

```
return this.http.delete(this.ApiURL, new RequestOptions({headers: headers,body: body }))
.map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

But got `net:: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` Also when I run this in POSTMAN it is successfully deleted.

Please guide

Comment: your question is very vague. Try to post some code snippets to explain what you need to accomplish

Comment: hi @rob-ot..sorry for this now i have edited my question....could you please guide me...

Comment: Post the server-side code which handles this request.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev there is no error response like above i mention in server side code.Why this happenning in case of delete. Also it is working in postman tool so api is right i guess.Please help

Comment: What's the HTTP status code returned by the server?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev The status is net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Which is not from the api thats y it is difficult to debug. What i think may be some issue with the browser or net connectivity dont know because the same thing is working fine in  postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the server returns an empty HTTP response body and status 200 OK. However, `HttpResponse`'s `.json()` method expects the body to be a valid JSON string. Since you don't have a body, the `.json()` method throws a `Unexpected end of JSON input` error. You also don't have a `.catch()` and this unhandled error propagates to the browser console.

One way to solve this is if you have access to the server side code. You can change your `DELETE` method's success response status code to be `204` ("No content"). In this way the `.json()` method will not throw an error, since it expects the response body to be empty.

The other way is to take for granted that if the status code is `200`, the deletion was completed successfully, and not to call `.json()` on the response object.